# VenueSearch method of Foursquare returns only the addresses in USA

Tags: foursquare

My app which implemented VenueSearch method of Foursquare returns only the addresses in USA whereas I am in Canada . The VenueSearch method requires two parameters which are ll(latitude & longitude) and query(searching string). What should I do to make it return addresses in my venue?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find venues near you, you should pass in a correct `ll`—one that is near you! You can also use the `near` param instead of `ll` and pass in something like `near=ottawa` and we'll use some basic geocoding to determine where that is.